# Tooltips or status bar not working in a PyQt app from Maya

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, maya

I've got a PyQt4 QDialog that I'm launching from python in Autodesk Maya. I want to have a status bar in the window or, if need be, tooltips. Maya doesn't seem to approve of either. I've implemented it using the method described here:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/10593-QDialog-StatusBar

If I launch my app standalone, both work correctly. Running from Maya, though, the status updates get sent to the general Maya status bar (which is not very obvious if you're in a different window), and Maya seems to steal the events completely from me: if I monitor the events that my event() method is getting, it never gets a QEvent.StatusTip event. I've tried swapping my QDialog for a QMainWindow, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Any suggestions for avenues to look down to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I'm working around this in a horrible way: subclassing each of widgets I want to use, and adding a signal to send to the parent, `self.setMouseTracking(True)`, and a `mouseMoveEvent(self, e)` that sends the signal to the parent. Then at the top of the tree I set the status bar. It's the sort of nasty code that makes me feel dirty, subclassing all the widget types, but it does seem to be working.
Any better suggestions VERY gratefully received!

Comment: Should revoke this as the accepted answer. This is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I need to tackle this as well, so your post was quite helpful.

When I have encountered event issues like this before, I solved it by using installEventFilter on all widgets (the same filter), rather than subclassing. Then you can receive and accept the events to block them from Maya (or let them through, e.g. space bar for marking menus over your gui, etc)

Here is what I use to let Maya have the spacebar (marking menus), ctrl+A (attribute editor toggle) and ctrl+Z (undo). This would be added to your event filter:

```
if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
    key = event.key()
    mod = event.modifiers()
    if ((ctrla and key == Qt.Key_A and mod == Qt.ControlModifier) or # CTRL+A
        (ctrlz and key == Qt.Key_Z and mod == Qt.ControlModifier) or # CTRL+Z
        (space and key == Qt.Key_Space)):                            # Space Bar
        event.ignore()
        return True

return False
```

You would just need to do the opposite and use `event.accept()` and `return False`

Answer (score 0):

For QWidgets, [colts answer here](http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php?t-1222763.html) is pretty good.

This is how I got it working for QActions:

```
class ActionFn(object):
    def __init__(self, action):
        self.action = action
    def __call__(self):
        self.action.parent()._displayStatusTip(self.action.statusTip())
```

Then after the action is created:

```
newAction._statusFn = _StatusTipActionFn(newAction)
newAction.hovered.connect(newAction._statusFn)
```

I hope this helps.